# Get and replace div background image url Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the div background url and replace it? Something like this:

```
<div style="background:url('images/bg.jpg')"> div content </div>
```

To this:

```
<div style="background:url('https://example.com/images/bg.jpg')"> div content </div>
```

Note: This page has multiple div to update background. All are different background. Just need to add `https://example.com/` before the current background image path.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the div and check the background. If it matches then replace the bacground

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((item) => {

  if (item.style.background === "url(\"images/bg.jpg\")") {

    item.style.background = "url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSvKv2QXuBZDwGEdEWTXoaM_twdWX5l_4-nUAgyBhH5AjtwOWAU')"

  }



})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:url('images/bg.jpg')"> div content </div>
<div style="background:url('images/bg.jpg')"> div content </div>
<div style="background:url('images/bg.jpg')"> div content </div>
```

Comment: Each div already have different background image. all background image are not same

Comment: Just need to add "https://example.com/" before current background image path. Like this "background:url('https://example.com/image/bg.jpg')"
"background:url('https://example.com/image/bg2.jpg')"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function() {
   var image = $(this).css("background");

   if(image=="url('images/bg.jpg')") {
      $(this).css({"background","url('https://example.com/images/bg.jpg')"});
   }
});
```

> Or You can do like this as well

You can do this by giving classes to particular `div` where you have to change `background-image`

```
$('.class_name_here').css({"background","url('images/bg.jpg')"});
```

Comment: need to get the current background image url and then replace it with new url. for example, get the current background image path `var currentUrl = currentbgurl` replace with `new_url + currentUrl`

Comment: you can get it by `var image = $(this).css("background");` or `var image = $(this).css("background-image");`

Comment: $(this).css("background-image"); returns "none" but if I try by div ID, it comes right thing. but I can't call them by ID. no ID in these div and the page has more than 1 div with background image.

Comment: some images are defined as just `background` that's why it respond `none`

Comment: no, the page has 3 div with inline background-image not only background. all are background-image

Comment: So it can be get by background.